# Are there any online tools to test SVG paths?

Tags: debugging, svg

I'm building an application that uses [SVG paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths), and I'd like to be able to see my paths rendered.  Is there a site, say something like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), on which you can paste in an SVG path, get it validated, and see it rendered?

**EDIT**: I've found that JSFiddle works fairly well for this, by selecting Raphael.js, svg.js, etc as a framework. e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/DFhUF/1393/

```
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 300, 500);

paper.path("M75,75 m-50,0 a50,50 0 1,0 100,0 a50,50 0 1,0 -100,0")
.attr({stroke: "#808", opacity: 1, "stroke-width" : 6})

paper.path("M75,225 m-40,-50 h80, a10,10 0 0,1 10,10 v80 a10,10 0 0,1 -10,10 h-80 a10,10 0 0,1 -10,-10 v-80 a10,10 0 0,1 10,-10")
.attr({stroke: "#808", opacity: 1, "stroke-width" : 6})
```

That's probably good enough for my needs, but it would be nice to know if there are other tools to help test and debug editing of SVG Paths.

Comment: Just open your .SVG in your browser. Or am I missing something?

Comment: not .svg files, SVG Paths.  as in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths though that is one way to do it, thanks.

Comment: Why not just put your path in an SVG `<path>` element and view it in the browser or the SVG viewer of your choice?

Comment: Be careful, Webkit and Opera 12 will both accept paths which are invalid according to the SVG specification.

Comment: Although it's frown up to, I have to say that this was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you just want to quickly try out some SVG in your browser and not mess around with saving and loading files, jsFiddle is a great option.

Just use the following code as a template:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="your path data here"></path>
</svg>
```

I created a [sample to work from here](http://jsfiddle.net/drewnoakes/GNm8W/).

jsFiddle also supports frameworks such as D3, PaperJs and Raphael from a dropdown on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 24):

## April 2023 Update

The landscape has changed in recent years; there are many more tools, both paid and free, to optimize, modify, and create `svg`'s

### My favorite tools

- https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ - incredible `svg` editor; **free**
- https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ - amazing `svg` optimizer; **free**
- https://figma.com/ - `svg` editor & a whole lot more; **must register**.

#### Other options in the wild

- https://svgedit.netlify.app/editor/index.html
- http://editor.method.ac/
- https://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/svg-viewer-editor.html
- https://vectorpaint.yaks.co.nz/
- https://editsvgcode.com/
- https://deeditor.com/
- https://svgeditoronline.com/
- https://editor.method.ac/
- https://cdnlogo.com/svg-editor/
- https://www.canva.com/features/svg-editor/
- https://boxy-svg.com/
- https://pixelied.com/features/svg-editor
- https://mediamodifier.com/free-svg-editor
- https://www.vecteezy.com/editor
- https://vectr.com/
- https://www.janvas.com/draw-edit-svg/en/index.html
- https://www.svgviewer.dev/
- https://vecta.io/

Answer (score 17):

You can use my helper web-page
http://naiksoftware.github.io/svg.html
[image]

Comment: Please describe how the helper-web page could help the questioner. Thank you.

Comment: One improvement: when the icons is large it doesn't fit the available space. You only see the corner of it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: your update didn't show for some reason before I posted this ...

Paste your SVG path into a text file with a .svg name, and open it in a browser.
Alternatively, create a small page like this

```
<html>
  <head><title>My SVG test page</title></head>
  <body>
    <h1>My SVG test</h1>
    <object id="SVG" type="image/svg+xml" data="MySvgTest.svg" 
      width="1000" height="1500"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

and open it in a browser (see [the Primer](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html#get_started)). It assumes your SVG is in MySvgTest.svg